# Non-standard distributions variables for KS testing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, normal-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

Could you use the kstest in scipy.stats for the non-standard distribution functions (ie. vary the DOF for Students t, or vary gamma for Cauchy)? My end goal is to find the max p-value and corresponding parameter for my distribution fit but that isn't the issue.

**EDIT:**

**"**

scipy.stat's cauchy pdf is:

```
cauchy.pdf(x) = 1 / (pi * (1 + x**2))
```

where it implies `x_0 = 0` for the location parameter and for gamma, `Y = 1`. I actually need it to look like this

```
cauchy.pdf(x, x_0, Y) = Y**2 / [(Y * pi) * ((x - x_0)**2 + Y**2)]
```

**"**

Q1) Could Students t, at least, could be used in a way perhaps like

```
stuff = []
for dof in xrange(0,100):
    d, p, dof = scipy.stats.kstest(data, "t", args = (dof, ))
    stuff.append(np.hstack((d, p, dof)))
```

since it seems to have the option to vary the parameter?

Q2) How would you do this if you needed the full normal distribution equation (need to vary sigma) and Cauchy as written above (need to vary gamma)? **EDIT: Instead of searching `scipy.stats` for non-standard distributions, is it actually possible to feed a function I write into the kstest that will find p-value's?**

Thanks kindly

Comment: It sounds to me like you trying to estimate the parameters of the distribution given some data? You should use the `.fit` method for the [corresponding distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Dang.. yeah I need to do individual KS tests for each parameter of the distribution, and cannot use the `.fit` method due to those corresponding distributions not accounting for the parameter examples above (sigma for norm, gamma for Cauchy), as they are the standard formulas and have simplified out the chance to vary those parameters. Let me add an edit for the visual.

Comment: @No, they haven't. For example, for the `norm` distribution, sigma corresponds to the `scale` parameter. mu corresponds to `loc`. Similarly, for Cauchy, gamma is `scale` and x0 is `loc`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh my, whoa. Whoa.. so can i vary them over `i` and `j` in some `cauchy(x, loc=i,scale=j)` way?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would solve your original problem, but you still likely want `.fit`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga And that would estimate the parameters for chi-squared to be minimized, right?

Comment: chi-squared to be minimized? No, it's the MLE. Why are you bringing up chi-squared?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I got confused with how the reduced chi squared played into curve_fit and leastsquared. Could you post in the answers section so that I can mark you as an accepted answer? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you really want to do is parameter estimation.Using the KT-test in this manner is not really what it is meant for. You should use the `.fit` method for the [corresponding distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions).

```
>>> import numpy as np, scipy.stats as stats
>>> arr = stats.norm.rvs(loc=10, scale=3, size=10) # generate 10 random samples from a normal distribution
>>> arr
array([ 11.54239861,  15.76348509,  12.65427353,  13.32551871,
        10.5756376 ,   7.98128118,  14.39058752,  15.08548683,
         9.21976924,  13.1020294 ])
>>> stats.norm.fit(arr)
(12.364046769964004, 2.3998164726918607)
>>> stats.cauchy.fit(arr)
(12.921113834451496, 1.5012714431045815)
```

Now to quickly check the documentation:

```
>>> help(cauchy.fit)

Help on method fit in module scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure:

fit(data, *args, **kwds) method of scipy.stats._continuous_distns.cauchy_gen instance
    Return MLEs for shape, location, and scale parameters from data.

    MLE stands for Maximum Likelihood Estimate.  Starting estimates for
    the fit are given by input arguments; for any arguments not provided
    with starting estimates, ``self._fitstart(data)`` is called to generate
    such.

    One can hold some parameters fixed to specific values by passing in
    keyword arguments ``f0``, ``f1``, ..., ``fn`` (for shape parameters)
    and ``floc`` and ``fscale`` (for location and scale parameters,
    respectively).

...

Returns
-------
shape, loc, scale : tuple of floats
    MLEs for any shape statistics, followed by those for location and
    scale.

Notes
-----
This fit is computed by maximizing a log-likelihood function, with
penalty applied for samples outside of range of the distribution. The
returned answer is not guaranteed to be the globally optimal MLE, it
may only be locally optimal, or the optimization may fail altogether.
```

So, let's say I wanted to hold one of those parameters constant, you could easily do:

```
>>> stats.cauchy.fit(arr, floc=10)
(10, 2.4905786982353786)
>>> stats.norm.fit(arr, floc=10)
(10, 3.3686549590571668)
```